# Внешний вид таблиц в базе данных PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Какими настройками поменять background полей (столбцов) таблиц?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять тему, например, на дракулу

Comment: Наверное это будет слишком общая настройка, а здесь надо поменять конкретно в БД, т.е. повлиять точечно ?!